# How to get current selected tab index in TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tablayout

When I use ActionBar tabs, I use this code.

```
private int getCurrentTabIndex() {
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    ActionBar.Tab selectedTab = actionBar.getSelectedTab();
    if(selectedTab == null){
        return 0;
    }

    return selectedTab.getPosition();
}
```

But how can I do it using TabLayout?

Comment: int tab_position=tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
same can be achieved without overriding ,I have tried it with targetSDK=24

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [OnTabSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener).

And then in this listener get the [`getPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#getPosition()).

Something like this:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int position = tab.getPosition();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

This method `setOnTabSelectedListener()` is deprecated . Use `addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)`

Comment: Note that if you are using [setupWithViewPager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) you should extend [TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html) instead of `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` and make sure to call it after `setupWithViewPager()` if you want to default integration with `ViewPager` functionality.

Comment: `setOnTabSelectedListener()` is now deprecated.

Comment: This method  `setOnTabSelectedListener()` is deprecated .
Use `addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)` instead.

Comment: onTabSelected is called with default value 0 after recreation, how can I save the last selected tab?

Answer (score 38):

**setOnTabSelectedListener** is now deprecated. you can use **addOnTabSelectedListener** instead. To remove the listener you can use  **removeOnTabSelectedListener**

```
 mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 33):

You can simply do it by calling `getSelectedTabPosition()` on your `TabLayout` instance like:

```
int tab_position=tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
```

and in Kotlin

```
val tabPosition = mTabLayout.selectedTabPosition
```

Comment: if you want the actual Tab `tabLayout.getTabAt(layout.selectedTabPosition)`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **tabs** with **viewpager** then the asked task could be done as follows:

use the following code after `tabLayout.setUpWithViewPager(viewPager)`

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch(tab.getPosition()){
            // do something here
        }
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
    }
});
```

Comment: setOnTabSelectedListener is now deprecated, you can use addOnTabSelectedListener. see reply of Doron http://stackoverflow.com/a/38094050/1970301

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TabLayout` inside `ViewPager` (and initializing it with `setupWithViewPager()`), you can do it using ViewPager instance.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager_tabs, container, false);
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = viewPager.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    int item = viewPager.getCurrentItem(); // get
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(item, true);  // set
```