# Android TabLayout Track change

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to catch the TabLayout changing when it is either clicked or the user swipes, but unfortunately Ive had little success getting this to work.

I was trying to add a addOnLayoutChangeListener to the OnCreate for my activity that creates the actual TabLayout but with little luck.

A couple of questions:

1. Is what I am trying to do the correct and best way to do this? I intend to have 3 recycler views that will be alternated between when the user clicks the TabLayout tabs.
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks again for any information or help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are Looking for is [TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)

So basically when you selected or click on any tabs you will get callback.
Here is sample code

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int position = tab.getPosition();
    }
});
```

Once you have index you can update you recycler view with different dataset or rather complete dataset.

Code reference from here [How to get current selected tab index in TabLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172729/how-to-get-current-selected-tab-index-in-tablayout)